# Java - Control console output in windows/linux

Tags: java, console

Does Java support controlling the cursor when outputting to a console?  For example, I'd like to set the character position, and possibly color, before doing a System.out.print().  Think of the way an application like top writes to the console.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You usually do not use system.out to do these things. most applications in *nix use NCURSES (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) for this. You can try http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/ if you need something this smart.

However, you can always sysout backspace (\b) characters if you want to delete what you wanted, and hope for the best

Comment: I agree with @Nir Levy. Consider however that this looks very aged for anything but perhaps some quick one-time installation interface.. Then again, I don't know what your constraints are. If at all possible, consider awt, swing or [swt](http://eclipse.org/swt/)

Answer (score 1):

Ha.  You can still do it in Linux.
Reference this man page for the codes themselves 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

```
public class quickTest{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
            //This will undo the current line by erasing it
            //and then putting the curser back at column 1
        System.out.println( "Hello.\u001b[1K\u001b[1GHi." ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  In the old days ANSI escape sequences was supported, but not anymore.

I would suggest you look into a good Java Curses library supporting Windows.  I cannot recommend any :(