# Graphically/Text display of thread progress and status

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, concurrency, console

I am working on a program (Java) that uses concurrent threading quite heavily. I run into issues with the work being performed by these threads very regularly. It's not an issue with the actual thread handling, instead it is the actual stuff it's doing (db access, math computations, file IO etc).

I would like to provide some way of seeing the status of threads in realtime from the console. Perhaps something like this:

```
THREAD ID   THREAD STATUS         TABLE NAME          ELAPSED TIME         
Thread 1:   Dumping               MSF011              22s
Thread 2:   Conversion            MSF002              2h 8m
Thread 3:   Conversion            MSF020              10s
Thread 4:   Loading               MSF001              14m

ITEMS LEFT IN QUEUE: MSF033, MSF123, MSFXYZ
```

sort of thing.

Ideally I'd like to see that updated in place (so no new lines etc, but I am open to ANY idea that lets me see information like this quickly.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207142/java-control-console-output-in-windows-linux) be relevant to what you are trying to do?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207142/java-control-console-output-in-windows-linux

Comment: It is, but I am looking for more ideas. I would rather use another idea then have to do it in NCurses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important is the console output? I mean, will other mechanisms (ie graphical) be ok?

Either way, I'd approach it as two steps.

1. [Instrument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation) your threads
2. Display the instrument data

### Instrument your threads

If JConole and the default thread information isn't enough (WAITING, stack traces etc), you can get your threads to post updates to their state as they go along. I like to use MBeans to do this so that way you can separate the posting of updates from the reading. Otherwise you could update some shared location with the state and have the reading done in the same VM. Perhaps even dumping process information to a file?

### Display the instrument data

Once you've got the threads updating the process information within, displaying it should be straight forward. If you *really* want the console output *and* to have it not scroll, I think something like ncurses is your only choice.

Otherwise, it's probably simpler to write a little UI that reads the instrument data and updates a display. You can read this data via the MBean server if your using MBeans (and so separate the UI physically from the server) or just read from say a file. JFreeChart is nice if you want some pretty graphs.

Having said all that, Haim has written a 'top' style thing to monitor threads. See [here](http://www.performize-it.com/tools/thread-top). Might be useful